# Python: How to set breakpoints on mac with IDLE debugger?

Tags: python, macos, python-idle

I have access to both a PC and a mac for a python class. I find I am unable to set breakpoints in the IDLE debugger in the mac (works fine on the PC).

I've tried "ctrl-click" and configuring the touchpad to recognize two taps at once as a secondary click. I don't have a mouse for the mac, just the touchpad.

MAC OS 10.4.10 tiger

Python/IDLE version 2.6.1

I have tried STFW unsuccessfully...

Answer (score 3):

If you put the following two lines:

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```

Python will import the **P**ython **D**e **B**ugger and you will be in the interactive interpreter at this point in the code. It will evaluate all your Python expressions normally.

The most important commands are:

1. s - step (forward one command)
2. c - continue (done)

For a full list, see this:
http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/python22/pdb-commands.html

Comment: ... or just type "help" at the debugger prompt. command-line debugging is something to get used to, but I find it incredibly helpful (I actually use pydb).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [pdb](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html) module.  I have just barely learned about it, and played with it a bit.  It appears to enable command line debugging by allowing you to set traces within the code.  This gives you interactive access to your variables and code while it is running. Not quite the same as running the IDLE debugger with breakpoints, but it may work for you.  
See [this](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html) or [this](http://www.ferg.org/papers/debugging_in_python.html) for more details.  
Something else to look at ... under Options -> Configure IDLE -> Keys, there may be a way to map keystrokes to the action of setting a breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in `IDLE`, specifically any `IDLE` on Mac OS X linked with the default Aqua `Tk`, supplied with Mac OS X or from ActiveState.  That includes the Apple-supplied Pythons in OS X 10.4 through 10.6 and the python.org installers.  The problem is that Aqua `Tk` has a different mapping for mouse clicks and, even if that were fixed, `IDLE` expects users to always have a multi-button mouse.  See [Issue 10404](http://bugs.python.org/issue10404) for more details and a patch.  This should not be an issue if the Python is linked with an X11-based `Tk`, as is the default with [MacPorts](http://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/x11/tk/Portfile).

Answer (score 0):

So, for newbies, a little more detail on Ned Deily's patch. Here  is what I did. I'm running python 2.7.1 in idle on osx 10.6.5. I followed Ned's link for Issue 10404, and finally to the patched version of the file EditorWindow.py, which on my installation lives in the directory

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/idlelib

Following more links, we find the patched version of the file is [here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/5f49d3cb194f/Lib/idlelib/EditorWindow.py).

This you can download from the "raw" link to the left on that page. Keep a copy of your old version of EditorWindow.py, then move or copy the new EditorWindow.py from your Download directory to the idlelib directory. Restart idle, and ctrl-click gives drop-down menus for setting breakpoints. This is probably all obvious, but it's the first time I did it so I thought I'd share the mini-steps with other novices. There may be a cleaner way to do it too of course.

Comment: Note that the patch was subsequently applied and is now included in the most recent Python releases, currently 3.2.2 and 2.7.2.

Comment: So, this is the first time I really sniff at python. :) 
Installed python 2.7.8 (the code I received was for it), but I can't right click. According to @NedDeily this should be fixed, but it doesn't so I tried your solution but now the 2.7.8 IDLE crashes on start... (Don't worry, I made a backup!). Yes, old thread, but google was useless for this issue.

Comment: @helmejo, sorry you are having problems. Note that the patch does not make right-click work on OS X for IDLE using native versions of Tk, rather it makes control-click work, like other context menus in OS X. (Right-click only works with an X11 version Tk on OS X.)  Beyond that, there are situations where the original patch did not work for certain configurations of IDLE on OS X where it should have.  It should work OK if you use the latest versions of Python (2.7.8 or 3.4.2).